# flutter giving me error (dont know why) (using flutter and Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Here is the code: (please reply with the error i cannot seem to find

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('MyApp'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[300],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text(
        'This is MyApp',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          letterSpacing: 2.0,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          fontFamily:
        ),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('  CLICK!'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[300],
    ),
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the font family value.

Example: `fontFamily: 'Raleway'`

Updated code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('MyApp'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[300],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'This is MyApp',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              fontFamily: 'Raleway',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(' CLICK!'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[300],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

[Use a custom font - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined **fontFamily** value.
You have to first import font and then you can define it.
It is use to set custom font.

Follow this steps to add custom font - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

And please make you code look clean and simple or post it like that.